# Given URL is not allowed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

if someone can help please help it will be appreciated 
actually i want to include facebook data in my website
and i am getting an error
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the *Website URL* or *Canvas URL*, or *the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains*
since i am new to php 
what should be come in place of

```
api('/me');
$userdata = $facebook->api('/me');
```

please someone help me i am frustrated
 here is the full code

```
<h1>Facebook SDK Login - Basic Information</h1>
<h4><a href='http://9lessons.info'>9lessons.info</a></h4>
<?php
include('lib/db.php');
require 'lib/facebook.php';
require 'lib/fbconfig.php';

// Connection...
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user)
 {
 $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
 try {
 $userdata = $facebook->api('/me');
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
 }
$_SESSION['facebook']=$_SESSION;
$_SESSION['userdata'] = $userdata;
$_SESSION['logout'] =  $logoutUrl;
header("Location: home.php");
}
else
{ 
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email,user_birthday'));
echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="facebook.png" title="Login with Facebook" /></a>';
 }
 ?>
fblogin.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Facebook App :-

`1.` click on "`setting`" tab(Basic)

```
 App Domains = example.com 

 site url = http://example.com/
```

(Advanced) tab

Age Restriction = 13+

`2.` click on "`Status & Review`" tab
Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? = Yes

only these option is required for create an basic app.

You can check for full doc :- [sourceaddons](http://www.sourceaddons.com/documentation.php) or [developer facebook](http://developers.facebook.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some parameters the API wants. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ the API expects the following syntax:

$ret = $facebook->api($path, $method, $params);

So "/me" is the path, but the API does not know what you want to do.
Have a look at the examples like this one here that fetches the user's profile:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/4.0.0

Comment: here is full code of page which is creating error ie fblogin.php i have downloaded whole folder from a site and it contains many files

Comment: correct me if i am wrong i think /me can be replaced by my profile page address and sir please do look again i have edited my question

Comment: I still think the line $userdata = $facebook->api('/me'); in that code is wrong. There are no action/method and no parameters given.

Comment: actually i am trying to change and make it live in status and review but i am not able to perform a click action and it is showing that add an email address ..how to add an email address sir please help me out i am new to this section

Comment: Try changing the line to $userdata = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');

Comment: dear sir i have edited my question and you can look at it full code written for fblogin.php which is creating problem ..if i go according to you what code you prefer in place of that

Comment: The question is, what you actually want to achieve. You wrote you "want to include facebook data in my website". So what data excatly? Please be a bit more specific, thanks.

Comment: okk $userdata = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');  i have changed it but still getting the same error  actually i am little confused making an app live is different from fecthing users facebook profile data.....i am asking to you..?

Comment: i just wanted to fetch users profile details from facebook now i want your response...sir..?

Comment: sir can u just give me your emailid i can email all my files to you and can take a look into that.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you further then. Maybe you should join the developer group on FB: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ and ask there. Sorry!

Comment: k one more last i got everything but what should come in place of app domain....site url = http://example.com/